# Set default style and name it in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I know you can set a default style if you *don't* specify a `x:Key` property. (so it apply to all elements from the type specified in `TargetType`)

I want to use a key for inheritance (`BasedOn` property), but still keep it default.
I thought about creating another style who is just based on on the previous one. like this:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="name">
        //...
    </Style >
    <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="name"/>
```

But I would prefer it if there is a neater way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can set its name with **{x:Type}** markup extension:

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
  </Style>
```

This way it still is an implicit style but you can now inherit from it.

Here is a complete working sample:

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="AnotherStyle" TargetType="Button"  BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Background="DimGray" Name="Grid" DataContext="{Binding ExpandoObject}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="LOL" Style="{StaticResource AnotherStyle}"/>
    </Grid>
```

**EDIT**
As commented below, you do not event need to set x:Key as you can access it using x:Type only

Comment: You are right. But you don't even need to add x:Key="{x:Type Button}" as WPF does it for you behind the scenes. So if you create an implicit style (without x:Key) you can still reference it using {StaticResource {x:Type Button}}

Comment: Agree on that. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You use StaticResource:

```
 <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="name">
   //...
 </Style >
 <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource name}">
   //...
 </Style >
```

Comment: This is wrong, by giving an x:Key a value other than x:Type you will lose the implicit style behavior.